# Setting up a Pi as a remote server without router access?

Tags: networking, pi-4

I am on university Ethernet so cannot port forward. Essentially, I want to host videos on my hard drive connected to my Pi and then stream them on Kodi and Infuse on devices, preferably over SFTP.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you missing port forwarding? Do you want to stream from the RasPi to the internet?

Comment: @Ingo don't have access to router settings as using university wifi. Want to be able to stream remotely from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a network problem, not an issue belonging to Raspberry Pi but I will give a short answer to point you in the right direction. To get streams from a streaming server you have to connect to it using the port of the streaming program. If you want to do this from outside a protected network like your university wifi you have to use port forwarding on the networks gateway/router/firewall. Otherwise it would not be protected. Of course there are hacks to peek a hole into the firewall from inside the network. With **ssh** you can create a reverse tunnel from inside the network to a relay server on the internet. It could just also be a RasPi that you can reach from the internet. Then you can connect to the relay server that will forward the traffic through the reverse tunnel to your RasPi inside the protected network. But because most security manager don't like this I will not elaborate on it.